# Is it possible to do 'live scrolling' on jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to have live scrolling feature on a grid I built using jqGrid. Anybody has done something similar? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jqgrid does support virtual scrolling since version 3.7, is that what you want?

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

see `New in version 3.7` -> `Virtual scrolling`